# Import CSV File data into DataGridView between two rows

Tags: sql, vb.net, csv, datagridview

I'm completely lost on this. Here's what's going on. I have a CSV file with a bunch of data, however I only need a certain piece of this data. There is a bunch of stuff online about selecting it by range (ex: F15:L20), but I don't know that data because it changes - depending on the number of entries.

Here's an example CSV file

```
NAME      RYAN
DATE      3/25/2014

ID        SECID         FID      LAST NAME      FIRST NAME          NOTES
1         3             1003     Doe            John                -
2         4             1004     Doe            John                -
3         5             1005     Doe            John                -
4         2             1002     Doe            John                -
5         1             1001     Doe            John                -
FINAL
ID        SECID         FID      LAST NAME      FIRST NAME          NOTES
**1         4             1004     Doe            John**              -
**2         5             1005     Doe            John**              -
**3         2             1002     Doe            John**              -
**4         3             1003     Doe            John**              -
**5         1             1001     Doe            John**              -
OTHER RECORDS
```

What I need imported is the `ID, SECID, FID, LAST NAME, & FIRST NAME` of everything that is `FINAL` (the range is selected by asterisks). Since we don't know how many records there are (5 in this case) I need to be able to do a search by the value `FINAL` and `OTHER RECORDS` then I can skip a row after `FINAL` and then select everything through column E (First Name) up until the point where the value `OTHER RECORDS` value is found.

Theoretically, I can just search the CSV file for `FINAL`, get its location and then do everything off of that. In this case it would be like this. `FINAL`'s location is A10. If we subtract the row value by 5, we will know how many records there are. Now we add skip row 11 and then select everything in A12 through E17 and we will get the values.

I'm sorry if this is very confusing. I just can't find a good way to explain it. I believe I  can get this to work by just searching the file for `FINAL` and getting it's location and then doing math to figure out how many records and then use a range to collect the data. However, I posted everything else in case someone had an easier way to do things. So my questions are how do I search a CSV file for a value and then get the cell location of that value, or if there is a better way to do this - How do I do this?f

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
  'Add a button and a datagridview to the form'
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strFilename As String = "C:\Junk\Junk.CSV"
    Dim blnFinal As Boolean = False 'wait until we find a line that says "FINAL"'
    Dim dtb As New DataTable
    dtb.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ID", GetType(String)))
    dtb.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("SECID", GetType(String)))
    dtb.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("FID", GetType(String)))
    dtb.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("LAST NAME", GetType(String)))
    dtb.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("FIRST NAME", GetType(String)))
    Using sr As New StreamReader(strFilename, False)
      Do Until sr.EndOfStream
        Dim strLine As String = sr.ReadLine() 'read a line'
        If Not blnFinal Then
          If strLine.ToUpper = "FINAL" Then
            blnFinal = True
          End If
        Else
          If strLine.ToUpper = "OTHER RECORDS" Then
            Exit Do 'finished'
          End If
          Dim strFields() As String = strLine.Split(","c)
          If strFields(0) <> "ID" Then 'ignore header row'
            dtb.Rows.Add(strFields(0), strFields(1), strFields(2), strFields(3), strFields(4))
          End If
        End If
      Loop
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dtb
  End Sub
End Class
```